# ASP.Net Membership configuration

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

I decided to use the ASP.Net Membership for my new web application. In my web config i've setup the connection string and membership provider. What bothers me is that the connection string is in plain text that contains the user and password (integrated security is not possible). Can anyone suggest a best practice solution to make this secure?

Answer (score 2):

You can [encrypt connection strings](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-webconfig/) in config files.

Encrypt:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pe “connectionStrings” -app “/DemoApplication”
```

Decrypt:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pd “connectionStrings” -app “/DemoApplication”
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt connection string.

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/07/29/Encrypting-the-connection-string-in-ASP.NET-V2.0.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really best practice but i don't like the idea that my hoster can decrypt it back. Any alternative?

Comment: You can encrypt it any way You want and store it encrypted in web.config. But You will still have to decrypt it during runtime. And if code for decrypting is on the server your hoster has access to it and can reverse engineer it.